# How to change price based on number of attributes?

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce with WordPress. How do I calculate pricing based on number of attributes selected as shown in the image. E.g. the current order should amount to Rs. 9100 as there are 9 attributes priced at Rs. 1000 each and Rs. 100 for the product base price.

Overall quantity for the product always is one.
[image]

Comment: @brasofilo removed from there. :)

Comment: Nine years later and we still see brasofilo's unhelpful comment, while the OP then provided a useful answer and solution. What a contrast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using Gravity forms and Gravity forms addon for woocommerce.

Next I created added multiple product fields which automatically come with *quantity* field and finished with the *total* field.

Next I created a product with and integrated it with gravity form I just created.. voila..

Edit: if you guys have any other creative of doing this. Please answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup product `attributes` and connect `variations` so 1 product can have multiple options which all influence the price. It is explained here:

http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/user-guide/product-variations/

Comment: that won't work, because they are not product variation. They are product addons which have can have any quantity the user desires.